# Struggling to LEFT JOIN On a SQL Table

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, database

I am currently working on a small project that is meant to allow a user to create, read, update and delete employees, departments and locations from a SQL database.

I am having trouble with the LEFT JOIN function as I am not too experience with SQL.  There are 3 databases:

1. Personnel,
2. Departments
3. Locations

They are organized like in the image attached.

[image]

I am trying to create a table for the user to view all Departments and their locations, however I am having trouble with this.  I am assuming I need to use LEFT JOIN for this but I am struggling to make it work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Liam

I have tried the following:

```
'SELECT d.id, d.name as departmentName, l.name as locationName from department d, LEFT JOIN location l ON (l.id = d.locationID)'
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue doesn't seem to be complicated at all, you were on good track - I've recreated your DB in SSMS and your query worked just fine once I removed the unnecessary coma before the 'LEFT JOIN'. This way you will get the departments without any location set too since you're using LEFT JOIN.

If you want to create a view out of this data just add ['CREATE VIEW view_name AS'](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp) before the query.

```
CREATE TABLE personnel (
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    firstName VARCHAR(255),
    lastName VARCHAR(255),
    jobTitle VARCHAR(255),
    email VARCHAR(255),
    departmentid int
);

CREATE TABLE department (
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    locationId INT
);

CREATE TABLE location (
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO location (name)
values
('Los Angeles'),
('Paris')

INSERT INTO department (name, locationId)
values
('Finance LA',1),
('HR LA',1),
('IT LA',1),
('Finance Paris',2),
('HR Paris',2),
('IT Paris',2)

INSERT INTO personnel (firstName, lastName, jobTitle, email, departmentId)
VALUES
('Joe', 'Bean', 'xxxx','xxx@xxx.com', 1),
('Jake', 'Blake', 'xxxx','xxx@xxx.com', 2),
('Chloe', 'Kashew', 'xxxx','xxx@xxx.com', 3),
('John', 'Cena', 'xxxx','xxx@xxx.com', 4),
('Matt', 'Hard', 'xxxx','xxx@xxx.com', 5),
('Paris', 'Hilton', 'xxxx','xxx@xxx.com', 6),
('Donald', 'Duck', 'xxxx','xxx@xxx.com', 1),
('Kyle', 'Hilton', 'xxxx','xxx@xxx.com', 2),
('Cart', 'Kashew', 'xxxx','xxx@xxx.com', 3),
('John', 'Blake', 'xxxx','xxx@xxx.com', 4),
('Cart', 'Hard', 'xxxx','xxx@xxx.com', 5),
('Matt', 'Hilton', 'xxxx','xxx@xxx.com', 6),
('Kyle', 'Duck', 'xxxx','xxx@xxx.com', 1),
('Matt', 'Bro', 'xxxx','xxx@xxx.com', 2),
('John', 'Man', 'xxxx','xxx@xxx.com', 3)

SELECT d.Id AS departmentId, d.Name AS departmentName, l.Name AS locationName FROM department d LEFT JOIN location l ON d.locationId = l.id
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to do that.  I really appreciate the help, that got it to work!